# Play and pause Mediaplayer with variable

Tags: java, android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to build an Android App where the user can play audiofiles labeled with an id from a database.

```
//get id from database and turn it into a string, add letter a, because its a res file
        stringId = "a" + String.valueOf(standard.getId());
        //find playbutton
        final FloatingActionButton play = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.play);
        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //to be able to feed mediaplayer a variable I put it in another function called playAudio
                playAudio(stringId, true);     }
        });

    final FloatingActionButton pause = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.pause);
    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            playAudio(stringId, false);     }
    });
```

The playAudio looks like this:

```
private void playAudio(String nameOfFile, Boolean booleanPlay){
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, getResources().getIdentifier(nameOfFile, "raw", getPackageName()));
        if (booleanPlay = true){
            if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
        if (booleanPlay = false){
            mediaPlayer.pause();
        }
    }
```

When I run my code every time I press play it creates a new mediaplayer which starts playing at the same time as the other mediaplayer, the pause button doesn't work for the same reason. I can't figure out how to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not create a new MediaPlayer instance each time you play a new file. Create an instance at the beginning and reuse it:

```
private static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer ();
```

When changing the file to play, try this piece of code:

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd = getApplicationContext ().getResources ().openRawResourceFd (R.raw.sound);

if (afd != null)
{
    mediaPlayer.reset()
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor (), afd.getStartOffset (), afd.getLength ());
    mediaPlayer.setLooping (true);
    mediaPlayer.prepare ();
    mediaPlayer.start ();
}
```

Replace *R.raw.sound* with the filename of the sound to play (this would be in the res/raw folder) or use a different way to reference the file as needed.

That works for me -- tested on Android 8.1 (targeted). Hope this helps.

**EDITED TO ADD**: I just noticed you have wrong operators in the *if(booleanPlay = false)* and *if (booleanPlay = true)* statements. They should be == (comparison, instead of assignment). 
And one last thing: When exiting, you should call *mediaPlayer.release()* to free up the resources, but you probably knew that. Glad I could help.